# Google Directions API using ExecutorService instead of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Every tutorial I find seems to use AsyncTask (depreciated) instead of ExecutorService. I took a java course on Udemy and they used AsyncTask for everything as well. Here is one class I'm working with:

```
public class FetchURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context mContext;
String directionMode = "driving";

public FetchURL(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    // For storing data from web service
    String data = "";
    directionMode = strings[1];
    try {
        // Fetching the data from web service
        data = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
        Log.d("mylog", "Background task data " + data.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    PointsParser parserTask = new PointsParser(mContext, directionMode);
    // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
    parserTask.execute(s);
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();
        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("mylog", "Downloaded URL: " + data.toString());
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("mylog", "Exception downloading URL: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
}
```

and I'd really like to use ExecutorService [like here](https://gist.github.com/sithu/7275635) instead of AsyncTask. I'm beating my head against the wall and I can't seem to get the proper arguments in and this thing working.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `AsyncTask` with a `Runnable`:

```
public class FetchUrl implements Runnable {

    public interface Callback {
        void onSuccess(String data);
        void onFailure(Exception e);
    }

    private String url;
    private WeakReference<Callback> callbackWeakReference;

    public FetchUrl(String url, Callback callback) {
        this.url = url;
        this.callbackWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String data = downloadUrl(url);
            Callback callback = callbackWeakReference.get();
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onSuccess(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Callback callback = callbackWeakReference.get();
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onFailure(e);
            }
        }
    }
    
    ... // include your downloadUrl function
}
```

Then create and submit it to the `ExecutorService`:

```
FetchUrl.Callback callback = new FetchUrl.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String data) {
        // handle your data
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
        // handle the exception
    }
};
Runnable job = new FetchUrl(url, callback);

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
executorService.submit(job);
```

Notice I used a `WeakReference<Callback>`, because code in your callback is holding a reference to `Context` and would cause `Context` leaks.

The `submit()` function returns a `Future` to control your submitted job. It's handy if you want to cancel the job or want to wait for its completion (blocking the current thread). The latter usecase would perhaps favor using `Callable<Result>` instead of `Runnable`, because the calling thread can handle the exception and there would be no use for a callback making your code more concise.

Also don't forget to call `shutdown()` on your `ExecutorService` when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not getting my polyline for the directions. I assume it's because I leave out my onpostexecute function, but how would I implement that?

Comment: You handle that in the onSuccess() callback where you get your data back. If possible do as much heavy work in the background, so maybe do the parsing also in the  `Runnable` and return your polyline as a final result.